# Clearing Confusion between LifecycleOwner & Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Describe about each , actually i'm confused while using the CoroutineScope associated with lifecycle-aware-components (Specially Activity ) like lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch{} and lifecyclescope.launch{} respectively . In case of first one CoroutineScope is tied to Lifecycle and in second CoroutineScope is tied to LifecycleOwner's Lifecycle( It's very confusing ) . Explain in point of an Activity UI Controller.

Comment: [`lifecycleScope`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/lifecycle/lifecycle-common/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleOwner.kt) is an extension property that returns `lifecycle.coroutineScope`. There is no difference.